# React component with i18n translation not accept string prop

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Need help with creating a component that uses i18n translation.
Component is very simply.

```
const TextInput = ({placeholder}: {placeholder: string}) => {
 const {t} = useTranslation()

 return (
   <Input placeholder={t(`${placeholder}`)} /> 
 )
}
```

When i using this placeholder prop like this i getting typescript error which says `No overload matches this call`, futher message inform me that prop is not part of translation json value. Any help how to solve it?